# Compare Between 2 NSDate

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate

i Have 2 `NSDate` object the first is set to one month ahead and the seconed is set for today.
i want to check if today is after (Bigger) then the month ahead object.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) a lot of Date & Time concepts (and how Cocoa handle them) are explained here in details, it is really worth reading.

Also, in the [NSDate class Reference, you can find a dedicated section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-SW6) "Comparing dates" for all the methods used to compare two dates. So you should use `laterDate:` or `earlierDate:` methods that totally answer your question. You can also use the `timeIntervalSinceDate:` method and check the sign of the returned time interval (see once again the documentation on this)

*In general, don't hesitate to **read the documentation** as **everything** is already explained in there in detail as you can see given those links*

Answer (score 11):

You can use [NSDate's `compare` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:). Example:

```
switch ([dateOne compare:dateTwo]) {
case NSOrderedAscending:
    // dateOne is earlier in time than dateTwo
    break;
case NSOrderedSame:
    // The dates are the same
    break;
case NSOrderedDescending:
    // dateOne is later in time than dateTwo
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDate* earlierDate = [aDate earlierDate:anotherDate];
```

**Return Value**
The earlier of the receiver and anotherDate, determined using timeIntervalSinceDate:. If the receiver and anotherDate represent the same date, returns the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

go to this link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

other wise convert your date to double and compare it. all related function are in this link.