# Fire Date issue in local notification

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I have a view controller which contains a field for user to enter date value.In contrast I have a field called "Remind Before Days" for the user to select when the notification should fire.If the remind before day is same day,then notification is set to fire on the date,but when the remind day is before 1 day,then notification should fire before one day the date set(specified).For this I have written a method called -(void)setNotification and here is the implementation code:

```
- (void)setNotification
{
    //Set notification after confirmation of saved data

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];

    if (cls != nil) 
    {
        textField = [self.fields objectAtIndex:3];

        if (textField.text == @"Same Day") 
        {
            notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
            notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        }
        else if(textField.text == @"1 Day")
        {
            NSDate *now = [datePicker date];

            // set up date components
            NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
            [components setDay:-1];

            // create a calendar to form date
            NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
            NSDate *newDate2 = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:now options:0];

            notif.fireDate = newDate2;
            notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        }
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notif.alertBody = textView.text;
        notif.alertAction = @"View";
        notif.soundName = @"lazy_afternoon.mp3";
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        textField = [self.fields objectAtIndex:1];
        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.textField.text forKey:kReminder];
        notif.userInfo = userDict;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [notif release];
    }
}
```

Now as we are all aware that when the notification gets fired,the user clicks view.Then we show an alert,the implementation code is written in appDelegate.Here it is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    

    // For The Purpose Of Notification.
    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls) 
    {
        UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:
                                             UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

        if (notification) 
        {
        NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:kReminder];
        [self.viewController showReminder:reminderText];
        }
    }

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Now after local notification is received,we do the following i.e.:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:kReminder];
    [self.viewController showReminder:reminderText];
}
```

Now I have set the -(void)setNotification action to right navigation right bar button item titled "Save" as follows:

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
[self setNotification];
}
```

When I don't specify any condition for fire date i.e. simply assign as :

notif.fireDate = [datePicker date]; everything's fine with notification(no issues).

But when I do as the above i.e. condition for fire date,then the notification is not getting fired.Instead the alert is getting fired when I click save.Also when I quit the simulator,I could see some thread problem.I don't understand what's wrong with the code (implementation).I have gone through several links,also the apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of UILocalNotification.Couldn't find out any property or method to set fire Date according to conditions.

I found out a method "repeatTimeInterval" which is relavant and applicable when a notification must be repeated weekly,yearly etc..which doesn't suit the requirement that the **"date to be fired is this when the remind days in textField is this"**

Can any one please guide me right,

Thanks all in advance :)

Comment: does anybody find the post little lengthy??

Comment: @Sarah Sorry,I wanted to be specific so that the experts can understand the issue better and answer with ease.Can you please help me,thanks :)

Comment: can you explain me in brief as I am not able to read whole thing due to less timing.

Comment: Oh sure,I have a text field to select remind before days.If the remind day is same day then the notification fire date would be [datePicker date];When it is 1 day then notification should fire before 1 day selected from datePicker.But the notification is not firing,instead the alert is getting displayed which should be displayed when we click view button of notification,also when I quit simulator,thread problem's appearing,that's the issue,thanks :)

Comment: I need to rush. Still would tell you that put the breakpoints in your code and try to debug and you surely will get the bug. Sorry..

Comment: k ll do that,thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @Sarah Yeah,the bug is with mutable array i.e. "fields" Mr.Sarah,please have a look at this question when you find some free time,thanks a ton in advance :)

que:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091647/incorrect-number-of-objects-getting-added-to-mutable-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you check this link out you will find out. But from what I have seen the code you have provide is from this site anyway.

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/7/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt,but there in the code you can observe that there are no specific condition like if(textField.text == ...) notif.fireDate = [datePicker date],something like this,it was simply [datePicker date].Even that works in my case too.But as you see in my code snippet that I have specified condition for fire date.Then this issue arises,so please help me out,thanks in advance :)

Comment: Actually every things got settled when I solved the issue of properly adding text fields to array

Answer (score 0):

I know I arrived a little late, but for me, the error on your code is here:

```
if (textField.text == @"Same Day")
```

Because you can't compare NSStrings using the operator `==`. I think that if you use `isEqualToString:(NSString*)` it will work properly. It would be great if you could edit your original post and fix the code, so people looking for info about local notifications won't run into the same problem.

Comment: I came across this question because I had made a similar mistake to this answer - I compared a fire date of a notification like this `notif.fireDate > someDate` when actually you should be comparing dates like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120370/compare-between-2-nsdate